# Is an average vector of a list of normalized vectors normalized?

Tags: vector-spaces

Say we have a list of normalized vectors. Let q be a vector such that each kth component of q is the average of all the kth components of the normalized vectors. All vectors here have the same length. Is q normalized?

My intuition says yes, but I would like to see a proof.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, take the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.  The average is $(\frac 12, \frac 12)$.  For an even simpler example, try $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$

Comment: Actually, depending on the norm, the first isn't necessarily a counterexample. The second one works, though.

Answer (score 2):

For a counterexample, use $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Actually, depending on the norm, this isn't necessarily a counterexample.